# How Memory allocation Happen in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to c++ and as an exercise trying to print an array using a function. I created two arrays `arr` and `arr2` as following.

```
int main(){

int arr[5] = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

int i =1;
int* arr2 = &i;
*arr2 =1;
*(arr2+1) =2;
*(arr2+2) =3;
*(arr2+3) =4;
*(arr2+4) =5;

printArray(arr2,5);    
printArray(arr,5);
}
```

I'm trying to print those two arrays using the function below.

```
void printArray(int arr[],int size){
   for(int i=0; i<size; i++){       
      cout<<*(arr+i)<<" ";
   }
   cout<<endl;
}
```

The result after running the program is,

```
 1 2 3 4 5
 2 3 4 5 15
```

But the expected result is,

```
1 2 3 4 5
11 12 13 14 15
```

Can someone explain what is happening here, If it is a problem with memory allocation highly appreciate if you can explain with a proper diagram.

Comment: You have *undefined behaviour*. `arr2` doesn't point to a block of 5 `int` but just one `int`. So, `*(arr2+1) =2; *(arr2+2) =3; *(arr2+3) =4; *(arr2+4) =5;` all access outside of the bounds. The same problem persists when print `arr2` in `printArray()` function.

Comment: This is undefined behavior

Comment: As already pointed out this is UB and apparently your compiler decided to allocate `i` right before `arr` so that `(arr2 + 1) == &arr[0]` - but this is in **NO** way correct or guaranteed (different compilers or just changing optimization level might already cause completely different effects)

Comment: Why C++ and DMA tags, when you have not used any of them. This code will have same undefined behavior even in C.

Comment: @programmerDaemon: C and C++ are different languages. OP uses C++, so the C++ tag is correct. The C tag is wrong! The C standard has a defect for exactly this situation, which was already discussed here.

Comment: Don't use C-style arrays, use `std::vector` and `std::array`.

Comment: "I created two arrays `arr` and `arr2`" - no, you didn't. You created one array and one pointer. There is a list of good books [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables you are declaring are declared on the stack:

```
int arr[5] = { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 }; // 5xsizeof (int) bytes
int i = 1; // sizeof (int) bytes on the stack
int *arr2 = &i; // sizeof (void*) bytes on the stack
```

Now `arr2` is a pointer to an `int`. In another context it could be a pointer to a dynamically allocated array, but here, it's not: it is pointing to the location of `i` on the stack. When you do:

```
*(arr2 + 1) = 2;
```

You are assigning `2` to another address on the stack (the one that comes right after `&i`) and from your result it looks like it coincide with the address of `arr[0]`, which is kinda logical (but well since it is undefined behavior, anything could happen).

Since you are assigning to addresses on the stack, you don't get a segfault but you do **corrupt** the stack however, which is much worse than getting a segfault:

- A segfault is a clear signal telling you you are trying an illegal memory access. You know where it takes place and you can fix it.
- Stack corruption happens silently and can go unnoticed until it crashes the program, which could happen anywhere. It is the result of an "illegal" memory access that goes undetected because the stack is already reserved for your program. Of course, debugging it is very hard since the crash can happen in a place that is completely unrelated to the faulty code.

Comment: "much worse than getting a segfault" I would suggest that a segfault is one of the *best* symptoms of UB to get, because it so loudly tells you things are wrong, and where to start looking

Comment: @Caleth Which is exactly why I said a silent stack corruption is much worse than a segfault. Maybe you mean to rephrase it to make look a segfault as a positive thing?

Comment: Yes. Silent stack corruption -> ignored/not noticed -> bug in production. Segfault -> identified -> fixed

Answer (score 2):

`arr2` is not an array. It is pointer to `int i`. You are reading from memory that is not yours.

Instead, use:

```
int* arr2 = new int[how_long_array_you_want]
```

Do not forget to delete `arr2`.

Comment: Please don't recommend raw pointers, C-style arrays and `new` / `delete` to new C++ programmers.

Answer (score -2):

wow no sigsegv?
Just a combination of factores, probably (inside the machine) the variable i get declared before the array.
So you cannot do it.
the variable "i" allocate just a slot for an integer.  but you need 5. when you do *(arr2+1) you are going to write in a ungulty,neighbour random variable. In this case proably the arr[]. Luckily is also an integer, otherwise you are going to get a SIGSEGV error
So the code is going to be

```
int i[5];
int *arr2=i;
```

so it works

Comment: *"Luckily is also an integer"* - no... just because you point a pointer to an adress does not mean that some underlying data type has to be present there. Also it doesn't *work*, it's undefined behavior that just happens to have this exact effect on OPs machine and compiler

Comment: Segfault has nothing to do with the underlying type of the attempted access. Here it does not segfault because each `arr2 + i` points to memory on the stack.

Comment: *"Luckily yhe pointer fall inside your heap"* except it doesn't, the pointed to address is on the stack.

Comment: You are right. The world,like the memory divide him self at least in two categories. Those who know the name of the memory and cannot use it, and those that doesn't know their name, but can use it. I just call it the memory allocated of the program compiling time. The other is the memory dinamically. How in China call the one or the other never cared about... Please check for my typo now.

Comment: This answer is unclear at best, when it's not just plain wrong. As is, it deserves its downvotes.